# Cannot find class `IgniteJdbcThinDataSource` for JDBC

Tags: ignite

I am following this [example for JDBC](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/jdbc-driver#section-ignite-datasource) given on the spark website. However, I am unable to find the `IgniteJdbcThinDataSource` in ignite-core or any other package. I even search in maven with `fc: org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDataSource` [search.maven.org](https://search.maven.org) but I cannot find this class anywhere. 
Can anyone please help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like, `IgniteJdbcThinDataSource` was added as a part of the following feature: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-6140 and it is marked as fixed in 2.6. I just checked and `IgniteJdbcThinDataSource` is already available on the master branch https://github.com/apache/ignite, so you can try to build it from sources.